# 128x64 LCD install to Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w, wiring, lcd

This is my first Rasp project, so please be understanding. I have Raspberry Pi Zero W and 128*64 dot china LCD. I do not have any program done for the screen yet.

When start my Rasp only backlight wake up. Is it normal if I do not have program for it? I just thinking something must happen when the screen got power.

Screen: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1420941126.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4djIZQCE

[image: This is diagram of the screen]

Now I have connected screen like this. Is those right? (screen pin left rasbpi right):

GND -> 20 GROUND

VCC ->  2  5V

RS  -> 24 GPIO8 CE0_N

R/W -> 19 GPIO10 MOSI

E   -> 23 GPIO11 SCLK

RST -> 22 GPIO25

BLA ->  2 5V (backlight VCC)

BLK ->  6 GROUND (backlight GROUND)

Comment: I have now attached datapins also to 8-bit mode all 8 datapins of the lcd. Tried to make program with C like here: http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-lcd-set-up-and-programming-in-c-with-wiringpi/

Wired same, also changed pin numbers in program. Still not working.